# Chess books that don't require a board

Tags: books

I am looking for some chess books suggestions that can be read without the need for a board, so I can read them during my commute time.

I am a ~1900 strength player, I can visualize the board, but not to the point where I can read a standard chess book while I commute.

I am looking for some books that focus on chess ideas, which are divulgated textually, rather than through variations with complex notations.

Comment: It's 2021. Can you not use a cheap smartphone and Lichess or another board editor?